# How to get primary key from template in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here I am trying to get user_to_toggle id but that is coming none and i guess this is because i am doing something wrong. I am confuse that how can i get user_to_toggle id. I am getting his username but i want user id too. Here is my code.

views,pyy

```
class UserProfileFollowToggle(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            user_pk_to_toggle=kwargs.get('pk') #this is returning None. 
            username_to_toggle = request.POST.get("username")#this is returning me username of toggle user. 
            profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, request.user.id ,username_to_toggle)
            return redirect(f'/profiles/{username_to_toggle}')
```

follow_to_toggle.html

```
<form class='form' method='POST' action="{% url 'profiles:toggle'%}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='username' value="{% if username %}{{ username }}{% else %}hello{% endif %}">
<button class='btn {% if is_following %}btn-warning{% else %}btn-primary{% endif %}'>{% if is_following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}</button>
</form>
```

if more code is required than tell me i will update my question with that information.

urls.py

```
app_name = 'profiles'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('user-profile/',UserProfileFollowToggle.as_view(),name = 'toggle'),
        path('<str:username>/',UserProfileDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail'),
    
    ]
```

Comment: Add url file which is related to this view.

Comment: I have added them. You can see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kwargs.get('pk')` returns `None` because you haven't supplied any keyword argument actually. If you want it to return a value your url path should look like `user-profile/<int:pk>/`. Thus you should change your template accordingly `{% url 'toggle' user_to_toggle.id %}`. You need to pass `user_to_toggle` object to the context when rendering the page or to retrieve it somehow else, probably through related model object.